# Streaming API push notifications not working

Tags: streaming-api, workbench, pushtopic

I'm trying to use push notifications in my developer org. I'm trying this from workbench as well as a VF page that I created but this doesn't seem to be working. I'm not getting any error message. I was able to subscribe and the polling seems to be happening fine. So there seems to be no issue with the CometD server. 
What do you think is the issue?

Comment: Did you find the problem, akash ? I'm stuck with a similar one.

Comment: Nope. I guess there's no solution for it. Can't waste a bounty on this

Comment: What does your PushTopic Query look like? I'm assuming you followed this tutorial: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/create_a_pushtopic.htm. I followed this one and just modified the query to an object that exists in my org and had no issues.

Comment: Did you found any solution

Comment: Use Version 36 it is working!!!